# How can i get my image to to completely fill my div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a hero image that would fill the div to my web page.  I've tried setting the width and height to 100%, but for some reason the image will only fill the div to about half way.

Here's the CSS and HTML [Im trying to get the image to fill the entire screen but it wont work for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xg4w.jpg)

```css
div.hero{
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#imghero {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="hero">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xg4w.jpg" alt="laptop" class="imghero">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div> 
</main>
```

Comment: #imghero should be .imghero, because you are setting a class attribute on image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see others here recommend going with the background-image, but I would suggest using an actual image element instead, and scaling that with `object-fit: cover`. There's two reasons for that.

1. You get the SEO and accessibility benefit of having an actual image element
2. It gives you all the benefits of image elements, like using srcset to serve different sizes to various devices, using lazy loading etc...

Here's how you do it:

#### Html

```
<div class="container">
  <img
    src="imageurl.jpg"
    srcset="*optional*"
    sizes="*optional*"
    alt="My image"
  />
</div>
```

#### Css

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;   /* Or whatever size you want */
  height: 50vh;  /* Or whatever size you want */
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

If you don't have a fixed with/height on the container, you can use an aspect ratio instead like this:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 aspect ratio */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just what i needed i didn't want to make the image as a background for scaling reasons. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set **Width & Height** also to the image, not only max-width & max-height

```css
div.hero{width : 100%; 
 height: 100%;margin:0 auto; }
  .imghero{max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
height: 300px;
width: 100% !important;

}
```

```html
<main>
 <div class="hero">
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xg4w.jpg" alt="laptop" class="imghero">
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
 </div>
  
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.imghero`  instead of `#imghero`, you are declaring imghero as class

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a background image to div

```css
.hero{
  background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQc-z-m2WiHy9yx9AfLg_YEi6mzltIlkaY_JGrIhP8d8mh_wMpB");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;


/*this is optional*/
min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
    <main>
 <div class="hero">
 <h1>Welcome</h1>
 </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put an image straight in the div, I'd add as a background image.

```
<main>

    <div class="hero">

    </div>

</main>
```

and for CSS

```
 .hero {
   background-image:url(image address here.);
   padding-top:300px;
   padding-bottom:300px;
}
```

The padding in the CSS adds height to the div, handy if you want to add text in there.

Or you could replace the padding with `height: auto` to fill the entire browser height.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the `img` tag, you can't manipulate the image widths and heights, it's max-width and max-height will be that of the image.

In order for you to get it to span a full width / height, you'll need to add it as a background-image attribute. Then you can set the widths and heights on the `div`.

`HTML` (note, we don't include the image here we do it in the CSS):

```
<main>
  <div class="hero imghero">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
</main>
```

`CSS`:

```
.hero  {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}

.imhero {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xg4w.jpg") no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;

}
```